# jQuery Page Transitions - can't target html?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add jQuery page transitions to my website and am running into the error message:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of null"

**jQuery Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var speed = 'medium';

$('html, body').hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html, body').fadeIn(speed, function() {
        $('a[href], button[href]').click(function(event) {
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if (url.indexOf('#') == 0 || url.indexOf('javascript:') == 0) return;
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').fadeOut(speed, function() {
                window.location = url;
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I have this code right before the closing head tag. I've also tried taking out 'body' and leaving them all as just 'html' since that tag is loaded. It works really well in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/akashacisne/hu9wW/ but doesn't work at all on my website?

The fiddle says to put it in the head, so why won't it work?

Is it because the html tag on our site is

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

Shouldn't it still be able to target 'html'?

Comment: According to your comments in the answers i think you **aren't** loading the `jQuery` correctly. is your page online?

Comment: It is not. I'm using this to load jQuery at the top of the header.
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> and I can click the link once the page is loaded on the local server and it shows minified jquery source.

Comment: I think the problem was with `document.ready`. Check my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25410346/2389232).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need put the `jQuery` lib before your `script` tag. Also i suggest you use `display: none` in html and body:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
     /* html and body hide by default */
     body, html { display: none } 
  </style>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.min.js'></script> <!-- Load jQuery -->
</head>
<body>
   <p>This shows how to make aesthetically-pleasing page transitions with jQuery.</p>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var speed= 'slow';
    $(window).load(function() { // When jQuery is loaded and document is ready
        $('html, body').fadeIn(speed, function() { //Show the body and html with effect...
            $('a[href], button[href]').click(function(event) {
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                if (url.indexOf('#') == 0 || url.indexOf('javascript:') == 0) return;
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').fadeOut(speed, function() {
                    window.location = url;
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The element's order in HTML is very important. If you use `jQuery` you need declare before. Also i suggest you always declare your script at the end of `body`, so the page is loaded before.

**UPDATED**:
If you don't want use the CSS solution, you can `hide` when `document` is `ready`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('body, html').hide();
      .....
```

But it's not a good solution because then the page could show a milisecond before to hide.

**UPDATED 2**:
Probably when you try to get access to `body` and `html` returns `undefined` because the page isn't loaded fully.

Change the `ready` event to `load`, so the event is called when page is loaded fully:

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

Comment: I do have the jQuery lib called before the script. I moved the script to just after the <body> tag and it still says it cannot read property hide of null. The other jQuery on the page works just fine (it just gives a class to a button when pressed)

Comment: You can't get the `body` and `html` because are not loaded. Use my CSS solution because you couldn't edit the `body` and `html` well. If you use the `hide` on `body` `onload` the page shows a milisecond before to hide... Also you can use a `wrapper` solution like @JorgeSilva says.

Comment: I'm thinking there must be some issue with using it in Magento... the script is after my <body> tag, the css is in place, and I tried using the div wrapper but it still always says Cannot read property 'hide' of null

Comment: In my first code I don't use the `hide` function, so these error mustn't appear. Check the cache. If your page is visible pass it and I can search the error.

Comment: Okay once I got past all that it now says it Cannot read property 'fadeIn' of null. Uhhh. But I am pulling jquery with this
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> right after the opening head tag

Comment: I have changed the `ready` to `window` `onload` event. According to `jQuery` documentation the `ready` event is fired before the page loads fully. See my updated.

Comment: Window load fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap everything in a div and then fadeIn/Out that div.

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <!-- ALL YOUR HTML -->
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// The speed of one transition (fadeIn or fadeOut).
// Full execution time will be:
// (browser navigation time) + speed * 2;
// You can set this to slow, medium, fast, or number of ms.
var speed = 'slow';

$('#app').hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#app').fadeIn(speed, function() {
    $('a[href], button[href]').click(function(event) {
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      if (url.indexOf('#') == 0 || url.indexOf('javascript:') == 0) return;
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#app').fadeOut(speed, function() {
        window.location = url;
      });
    });
  });
});
```

If you want to write even better javascript, you can cache your jQuery object.

var $app = $('#app');

```
$app.hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $app.fadeIn(speed, function() {
    $('a[href], button[href]').click(function(event) {
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      if (url.indexOf('#') == 0 || url.indexOf('javascript:') == 0) return;
      event.preventDefault();
      $app.fadeOut(speed, function() {
        window.location = url;
      });
    });
  });
});
```